# Intrusive ref count w/ action on destruction

Tags: c++, reference-counting, crtp

I have a mixin class that makes a class reference counted that looks like this:

```
template<class D>
class ref_count_base
{
protected:
    ref_count_base();
    ref_count_base(ref_count_base const& x);
    ref_count_base(ref_count_base&& x);
    ref_count_base& operator=(ref_count_base const& x) &;
    ref_count_base& operator=(ref_count_base&& x) &;
    ~ref_count_base();

private:
    int* refs_;
};

// omitted constructors...

template<class D>
ref_count_base<D>::~ref_count_base()
{
    if (!refs_)
        return;

    if (1 == *refs_) {
        // C-style cast rather than static_cast allows us to call a member
        // function in the derived class even if we are a private base.
        ((D*)this)->last_ref_released();
        delete refs_;
    } else {
        --*refs_;
    }
}
```

This class is then used like this:

```
class program : private ref_count_base<program>
{
private:
    void last_ref_released()
    {
        glDeleteProgram(name_);
    }

private:
    GLuint name_;

    friend ref_count_base;
};
```

Obviously this doesn't work, because `program` is no longer alive when we reach the mixin's destructor and so we can't call `last_ref_released` in the derived class, but is there a similar way to accomplish this (preferrably without adding noise to the derived class)?

Edit: here is an example of client code:

```
class entity
{
private:
    // some other data members...
    program prog_;
};

std::vector<entity> entities_;
for (auto& i : entities_) {
    //i.bind_program();
    glUseProgram(i.get_program_name());

    // drawing code here...
}
```

Note that with a `shared_ptr<program>` instead of a `program` this will look
like `glUseProgram(i->get_program_name())`.

Comment: what's this syntax `ref_count_base& operator=(ref_count_base x) &;`?

Comment: @billz I like to call it a uniform assignment operator. The operator isn't a problem. Edit: actually I just noticed a problem with it, but ignore it for now.

Comment: You can have an assignment operator that takes its argument by value, which accepts both lvalues and rvalues. It was used a lot in C++03 to do copy-and-swap. Again, I noticed a problem with it in this particular case, but usually it's fine.

Comment: It's the `) &;` part I'm not sure about

Comment: Oh. That's a ref-qualifier. It means `operator=` can only be called on an lvalue.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't come across that.

Comment: In your example, `i` is a reference: how is the cache behaviour of a reference different from that of a pointer? A reference is just a pointer you can't re-seat. Also ... does `entities_` store entity instances? Because it's not clear how the program instance can be usefully ref-counted in that code.

Comment: Each entity has a `program`, some of which are the same program (ref counted). The `name_` is in cache at this point because the contents of the `vector`'s storage is in cache and the `program` is just a data member (not a pointer).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43318/discussion-between-useless-and-simple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: the confusion was that you're not trying to *reference count the `program` class*, but to *reference count copies of `name_` with the same value*.

Given this, it seems cleaner to create something with similar semantics to `shared_ptr`, but for value types ... let's call it `shared_value`:

```
template <typename T, void (*Deleter)(T)>
struct shared_value {
    typedef shared_value<T,Deleter> Self;

    // whatever ctors, assignment operators etc. you need here:
    shared_value(Self const &other)
    : value_(other.value_), refs_(other.refs_) {
        ++*refs_;
    }

    ~shared_value() {
        if (resf_) {
            if (*refs_ == 1) {
                Deleter(value_);
                delete refs_;
            }
            else
                --*refs_;
        }
    }

    operator T& () { return value_; }
    operator T const& () const { return value_; }
private:
    T value_;
    mutable int *refs_;
};
```

and use it like:

```
class program {
    shared_value<GLuint, glDeleteProgram> name_;
};
```

You can add flexibility with a polymorphic deleter here - I've just shown the simplest thing that should work for you.

---

There's an easy way to do what you want, without using CRTP or mixins or touching the program class at all. Simply write it like this:

```
class program {
    GLuint name_;

public:
    ~program() {
        glDeleteProgram(name_);
    }
};
```

and then use `std::shared_ptr<program>` everywhere you currently use `program` (that is, only create one instance and then pass around shared pointers to it).

If you don't have `std::shared_ptr` yet, use `boost::shared_ptr` instead.

Comment: The reason I'm not using `shared_ptr` is because I don't want to dereference a pointer every time I call a member function on the `program`.

Comment: Dereferencing the `shared_ptr` will likely cause a cache miss. Dereferencing `this` won't.

Comment: So following a pointer stored in a (local) shared_ptr, via an in-lined `operator->`, is somehow different to following a raw pointer? Unless your program object is on the current stack frame (in which case it can't be refcounted), I don't see why there would be a difference.

Comment: With an intrusive reference count, there is only a cache miss when the `program` is copied or destroyed, both of which only happen at an acceptable time. The `program` is going to be in cache when I need to get its `name_` to bind it, which means dereferencing `this` is free, whereas with a `shared_ptr` it's going to cause a cache miss every time I need to get the `name_` out of the `program`. `shared_ptr` isn't acceptable here.

Comment: This simply isn't true, unless you're concerned about accesses to the refcount, which only happens when the `shared_ptr` is copied or destroyed. Can you edit some sample client code into your question, where you believe `shared_ptr` will always cause an avoidable cache miss? This is getting too long & involved for comments ...

Comment: I quite like your new solution. The class that uses `shared_value` still looks very neat.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand `program` class is a thin wrapper over OpenGL program implementing RAII idiom. In such case you don't need to have special method `last_ref_released()` for all such refcounted objects. You just need to perform cleanup in destructor of `program` class.

```
//...
template<class D>
ref_count_base<D>::~ref_count_base()
{
    if (!refs_)
        return;

    if (1 == *refs_) {
        delete refs_;   /// cleaup performed there
    } else {
        --*refs_;
    }
}


//...
class program : private ref_count_base<program>
{
private:
    ~program ()
    {
        glDeleteProgram(name_);
    }

private:
    GLuint name_;
};
```